# Editable Spinner is not working properly in Android Programatically?

Tags: android, android-spinner

Please find the scrren shot below

[image]

Here, I have Spinner with EditText. User can choose spinner item or else can enter custom data (like 100 enterd by user in EditText). So i can able to get Spinner selected data based on position. But, when i'm trying to enter any data in edittext that is in spinner its automatically cursor going to below edittext.

So please help anybody to solve this issue. Thank you

I have done the below code for Spinner with EditText.

```
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter1 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( 
                this, R.array.my_array, R.layout.custom_spinner); 
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); 
        spinner_distance.setAdapter(adapter1);
```

In custom_spinner.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/custom_edit"

    android:hint="Enter"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:maxLength="3">
    <requestFocus />
    </EditText>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18713182/1576416 refer this answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

((EditText) spinner_distance.getChildAt(0)).getText()

As your spinner item is itself an edittext, so this will give u an edittext value.

Answer (score 0):

Use AutoComplete Text View

```
   ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( 
            this, R.array.my_array, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);  
   AutoCompleteTextView tv=   (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);  
       tv.setThreshold(1);
       tv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

in you xml file replace

```
 <Spinner ........./>
```

with below code

```
    <AutoCompleteTextView  
    android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"  
    android:layout_width="match_parent"  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
    android:padding="5dp"   
    android:ems="10"  
    android:text="100">  
    <requestFocus />  
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
```

Comment: where you declared layout of Autocomplete here ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource( 
            this, R.array.my_array, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);  
   AutoCompleteTextView tv=   (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteTextView);  
       tv.setThreshold(1);
       tv.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: just replace your  Spinner with AutoCompleteTextView @Siva Polam

Comment: So,that is entire we are displaying Autocomplete Textview only Right? not Spinner. But we need Spinner with Editable @Nooh